# How can I get all the records having the highest order number in Linq Query

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I am trying to find the list of records into an IEnumerable list from the records attached here having highest order number. I am using  the following models.How to get a linq to select the records having max OrderNo

```
 public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }       
}
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What is desired output for provided data?

Comment: I am trying to get the records having highest order number . The IEnumerable<Order> should  have been included four records , all the records having OrderNo 200.

Comment: Is this query against db or in-memory collection?

Comment: I am looking for something like query against db like IEnumerable<Order> =  _db.Order.OrderByDescending(b => b.OrderNo).max(). But it not working

Comment: @systemthreep try this query `List<Order> result = _db.Order.Where(o => _db.Order.Max(so => so.OrderNo) == o.OrderNo).ToList();` it's work in memory.

Comment: What LINQ are you using? LINQ to SQL / EF 6 / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x?

Comment: Your data has `Id` = 4 twice - is there an error. Don't put pictures of data in, put text in. What does highest order number mean when you have `OrderNo` is a `string`?

Comment: You can first select the max OrderNo, then select records with that OrderNo.

Comment: Oh Sorry OrderNo is an integer type. That was my typing mistake . Sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming u are working with DB

If u want just one round trip then

```
this.Orders.GroupBy(order=>order.OrderNo).OrderByDescending(group=>group.Key).FirstAsync()
```

it has lot of ordering.

and other solution is

```
this.Orders.Where(order=> order.OrderNo == this.Orders.Max(order=>order.OrderNo)).ToListAsync()
```